# jQuery UI widget CSS inhertiance issues

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a couple different types of UI widgets on my page. There is a class that is common between all of them `.ui-widget-content`. I need to style this class differently for each one, so I have assigned unique ids or classes to the HTML elements. This worked ok for one type of widget (dialog where I can use the `dialogClass` option in the JS to assign classes), but the other type of widget (slider) will still only inherit styles from `.ui-widget-content` even when I specify a style for `#id .ui-widget-content` to get at the specific element of interest. I'm kind of at a loss on how to override the original style at this point.

HTML:

```
<div id="opacitySlide" class="slider">
     <div id="opacityVal" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
<div id="habClassify-dialog" title="Habitat Classification">
    <div id="HabClassifyGPService">
        //whole bunch of stuff
    </div>
</div>
<div id="error-dialog" title="ERROR"></div>
<div id="success-dialog" title="SUCCESS">
    <p>Habitat classification completed successfully! Your results will be viewable in 10 minutes.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
//This one doesn't work and get overridden by the default style .ui-widget-content    
#opacitySlide .ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

//This one does work, these classes are assigned in the JS, NOT the HTML
.habClassify-dialog .ui-widget-content,
.error-dialog .ui-widget-content,
.success-dialog .ui-widget-content {
    border: none;
}
```

I've also attempted to use the custom class I assigned in the HTML instead of the id for the non-working CSS as well, but no luck.

```
.slider .ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here's the JS code:

```
//Creates the popup dialog for the habitat classification button
          var habClassifyDialog = $("#habClassify-dialog").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              height: "auto",
              width: 400,
              modal: true,
              dialogClass: 'habClassify-dialog',
              buttons: [{
                  id: "classify",
                  text: "Classify habitat",
                  click: upload
              }],
              close: function () {
                  $('#uploadForm')[0].reset();
                  $('#validation-text').empty();
              }
          });
      $('#classifyHab').click(function() {
              habClassifyDialog.dialog("open");
      });

      //Creates the popup dialog that contains error messages
      var errorDialog = $("#error-dialog").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: "auto",
          width: 1000,
          modal: true,
          dialogClass: 'error-dialog',
          buttons: [{
              id: "error-ok",
              text: "Ok",
              click: function () {
                  errorDialog.dialog("close");
              }
          }]
      });

      //Creates the popup dialog that shows the success message
      var successDialog = $('#success-dialog').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: "auto",
          width: 400,
          modal: true,
          dialogClass: 'success-dialog',
          buttons: [{
              id: "success-ok",
              text: "Ok",
              click: function () {
                  successDialog.dialog("close");
                  if (habClassifyDialog.dialog('isOpen')) {
                      habClassifyDialog.dialog("close");
                  }
              }
          }],
          close: function () {
              if (habClassifyDialog.dialog('isOpen')) {
                  habClassifyDialog.dialog("close");
              }
          }
      });

      //Create the opacity slider
      var handle = $("#opacityVal");
      $("#opacitySlide").slider({
          range: "min",
          value: 100,
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          create: function () {
              handle.text($(this).slider("value") + "%");
          },
          slide: changeOpacity,
          change: changeOpacity
      });
```

If you haven't used jQuery UI before, it automatically adds a whole bunch of default styles to the widgets upon load, that's why you don't see `class="ui-widget-content"` in my HTML anywhere, it's not necessary to declare it.

Comment: Why not use the `classes` option? Also would help if you provided a complete example with maybe some of your jQuery code.

Comment: @Twisty - I have updated with my JS code. I have attempted to use the `classes` option but don't notice any difference when using it. From my understanding, if I add `classes: {"ui-slider": "ui-corner-all myCustomClass"}` it's supposed to remove all classes from the slider and only use `ui-corner-all` and `myCustomClass` when something with class `ui-slider` is instantiated. Maybe I'm using it wrong?

Comment: It's also might be worth noting that `.ui-widget-content` isn't something that can be used in as a key in the classes option according to the Slider documentation. When I run the page, the script generates this HTML: `<div id="opacitySlide" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">` I was hoping setting the classes option with `ui-slider` as the key would work, but it doesn't change what is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I have officially made the stupidest mistake ever. Considering the HTML was generating with the correct custom ID I assigned, I figured there had to be a way to access the `ui-widget-content` class using that ID. It was as simple as chaining them together, before when I was testing this I had left a space in between.

Problem CSS (won't work):

```
#opacitySlide .ui-widget-content {
      border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Simple fix (remove space between id and class):

```
#opacitySlide.ui-widget-content{
     border: 1px solid black;
}
```

For the sake of completeness, the explanation is that if you leave a space between these items, it thinks the HTML is structured like this:

```
<div id="opacitySlide">
    <div class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

when really my HTML was structured like this:

```
<div id="opacitySlide" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
```